# HTML/CSS body property not working

Tags: html, css

```
body {
background-color: #0B0B0B;
background-image:url(resources/body.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

That is my CSS, it won't work when I put it on a style sheet file but it will work when enclosed in a a style tag. I've checked other questions and tried its solutions but none worked for me. Is there anything wrong with that CSS? Here's the body btw:

```
<body>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container">
<div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
<div id="slider">
<img src="resources/Slideshow/AvrilAlbum.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
<img src="resources/Slideshow/HTNGU.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
<img src="resources/Slideshow/LetMeGo.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
<img src="resources/Slideshow/OnTour.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
<img src="resources/Slideshow/LetMeGoBuyNow.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
<div><img src="resources/Slideshow/RockNRoll.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent"></div>
</div>
 <div class="controller" id="next"></div>
</div>
</div>
 <a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/AvrilLavigne" data-widget-id="436842073010888705">Tweets by @AvrilLavigne</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is you link that css file in your page?

Comment: Works for me. Could you be more specific?

Comment: please insert complete html code

Comment: The background-image link needs to be relative to the external css file

Comment: It seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/ApY3m/ where are you trying to load the stylesheet?

Comment: @SiddiqueMahsud this is the link to the css file
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: @Radian http://pastebin.com/AeBCe713

Comment: @inorganik what do you mean by relative? And there are 2 properties just in case one won't work, but the whole body property doesn't work.

Comment: @charlieg what do you mean by where am I trying to load the stylesheet? Forgive me, I'm very very new to this.

Comment: look at the answer by @TechnologRich - if you can't get rules in an external style sheet to work, either your linking the css wrong or your styles are being overwritten.

Comment: What is your directory structure

Comment: just change your style as folowing, also description is posted in answer below. background-image:url(../resources/body.jpg);

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS link should be contained in the head.

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bodyCSS.css">
</head>
```

This is when the CSS document is within the same folder as the html document. If your CSS document is outside of the html folders location. Then it needs to be:

```
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your/folder/bodyCSS.css">
</head>
```

And in this case. If your CSS document is in a DIFFERENT folder than your Background Image Folder, it will try to append the image link to the active folder of the html document. So it seems this is a case of misdirection on the background image location.

Comment: Then either the CSS document is not in the same folder as your html document, or your CSS document is improperly programmed.

Comment: So the .css has to be in the same folder as the .html? If that is the case, why do the other properties work?

Comment: if your css is in a different folder from your html, it could cause directory referencing errors. For instance: "web.com\css\body.css" looks for "web.com\css\resources\background.jpg" when it should be looking for "web.com\resources\background.jpg"

Comment: My CSS was improperly programmed. I realized this after rebuilding it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. Remember to mark an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in between your head tags?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOURCSSFILE.css">
</head
```

Also, make sure that you are using the relative link to your image.

Comment: What do you mean a relative link to the image? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Why is it that you posted exactly the same question twice in less than an hour?

Comment: I did not know about the editing, so I thought to fix it by posting it again but without external links.

Comment: Try changing .jpg to .JPG if that works let me know!

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't either.

Comment: @polors2 Try this: background-image:url(./resources/body.jpg);  or background-image:url(../resources/body.jpg);

Comment: Did you try my suggestion as seen above?

Answer (score 0):

how is the folder structure setup in accordance with your .css file?  Maybe try

background-image:url(../resources/body.jpg);

if the .css file is in a folder that is at the same level as your resources file

Comment: css\layout.css
javascript\jQuery.js
resources\body.jpg
index.html

Answer (score 0):

You are probably incorrectly linking your style sheet. Perhaps pointing it to the wrong directory. Can I see your head?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your style, when you linking that from file css/style.css.

```
body {
background-color: #0B0B0B;
background-image:url(../resources/body.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

because here you should use relative url to location resources/body.jpg, resources folder is not in the same level as you style.css.
From style.css you should move one step back by using **(../)** and then jumps to resources/body.jpg.
Hope by correcting your css,you solve your problem.

Your complete Html page is below, here i am just include head tag and link css file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />        
</head>
<body>
sam as your code....
</body>
</html>
```